# download files from vsts package feed

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have certain Chocolatey packages stored in VSTS private package management feed. I'm trying to download a specific package from feed in VSTS in PowerShell. I'm using the below commands:

```powershell
$user = "my-user-id"

$token = "my-pat-token"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$url = "vsts-package-url"

$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.Headers.Add('HttpRequestHeader.Authorization',"Basic $base64AuthInfo")
```

After this, I should be able to download the package when using `$webClient.DownloadFile($url, $fileName)`.

However file contains dummy text expecting me to sign-in and has 401 related details.

Its basically a PowerShell code. Can anyone please advise how should I go about this? I do not want to **install** the package from feed, only download it.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this as this process still needs me to prepare package url first which would be different for each package iteration?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating the auth header incorrectly. Basically, with a PAT, no user name is needed.

I use this snippet of code all the time:

```
$pat = 'yourPatHere'
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)")
$encodedText =[Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

$header = @{Authorization = "Basic $encodedText"}
```

You can then use `Invoke-WebRequest` to download the feed information:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://uri' -Header $header -Method Get
```

That looks roughly the same as your code, but `Invoke-WebRequest` is idiomatic PowerShell vs creating a `WebClient`. Shouldn't matter in the end.

Actually downloading a file from a feed is a different matter. The packages are exposed via standard mechanisms for that specific type of feed. See the [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/packaging/packages#protocol-endpoints). Basically, if you need a NuGet package, you download it from the NuGet feed, not from package management.

Comment: This works..however downloaded file is a json response instead of containing package data. The package uri I'm using is: https://myaccount.feeds.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/Packaging/Feeds/<feed_guid>/Packages/<package_guid>/Versions/<version_guid>